# Linq query to group items and query from the top item in each group

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

So, I have a list that looks something like this. Its basically a state history for a bunch of items, with the most recent state representing the current state.

```
Record   Id      State       Date
=====    ===     =========  =======
1        A       Waiting     Jan 01
2        A       InProgress  Jan 02
3        A       Finished    Jan 03
4        B       Waiting     Jan 02
5        C       Waiting     Jan 01
6        C       InProgress  Jan 02
7        D       Waiting     Jan 01
8        D       InProgress  Jan 02
```

What I'm looking for is to be able to query the 'current' state for each item.
For example, I'd like to say: "Give me all Ids are are 'InProgress'" and get Id D and Id C, but not Id A (because its latest state is 'Finished').

I know I've got to do some grouping and some ordering or Maxing, but I can't quite put it all together.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us what you've done with grouping ordering and max and we can tell you where you went wrong. Much better for learning than just being given the solution...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
myList.GroupBy(m => m.Id)
.Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).First())
.Where(<your filter>);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's some code to do what you want.  It gets the latest state for each id and ignores finished records.  I've provided a complete working example that you can run (and hopefully adapt to work for your real data).

```
//the example data provided by the OP
var data = new []
{
    new { Record = 1, Id = "A", State = "Waiting", Date = new DateTime(2013, 1, 1) },
    new { Record = 2, Id = "A", State = "InProgress", Date = new DateTime(2013, 1, 2) },
    new { Record = 3, Id = "A", State = "Finished", Date = new DateTime(2013, 1, 3) },        
    new { Record = 4, Id = "B", State = "Waiting", Date = new DateTime(2013, 1, 1) },        
    new { Record = 5, Id = "C", State = "Waiting", Date = new DateTime(2013, 1, 1) },
    new { Record = 6, Id = "C", State = "InProgress", Date = new DateTime(2013, 1, 2) },        
    new { Record = 7, Id = "D", State = "Waiting", Date = new DateTime(2013, 1, 1) },
    new { Record = 8, Id = "D", State = "InProgress", Date = new DateTime(2013, 1, 2) },
};

var query = from d in data
            //put the newest record first
            orderby d.Date descending
            //group by the id
            group d by d.Id into groupedById
            //get the latest record for each id
            let latest = groupedById.First()
            //filter out finished records
            where latest.State != "Finished"
            select latest;
```

And here's the output from LinqPad.

[image]

You'll notice that we have the latest state for each item, apart from "A" which has been ignored because it is finished.

Answer (score 1):

If this is LINQ to Objects (and assuming records are arranged in the right order), you can do:

```
var latestById = records.GroupBy(record => record.Id)
                        .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.Last());
```

This is because GroupBy [guarantees that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501.aspx) "Elements in a grouping are yielded in the order they appear in source."

If you can't make guarantees about the record order, I would do:

```
var latestById = records.GroupBy(record => record.Id)
                        .Select(group => group.MaxBy(r => r.Date))
                        .ToDictionary(record => record.Id);
```

where [MaxBy](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs?r=2da75c30d5bda7959e5113b702b4bb204a0e4a2c) comes from [moreLinq](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/).

By the way, if this were LINQ to SQL, I would do:

```
var latestById = records.GroupBy(record => record.Id)
                        .Select(group => group.OrderByDescending(r => r.Date).First())
                        .AsEnumerable()
                        .ToDictionary(record => record.Id);
```

Comment: We don't know that the order they appear in source is date order do we? They are in the example but he hasn't said that the records are in date order. Nitpicky but its the sort of thing that is the source of bugs...

Comment: @Chris: It appears to be that way, but I've provided a way if that were not the case.

Comment: Thanks Ani. I think that makes it a much better answer. :)